# Email :hover link not working

Tags: html, css

I have a div that includes contact information at the top left of the website.  I want the top of the background to hide behind the blue header, but I want the email link to underline when I hover over it.  By using z-index, I can get the email link to underline but the top of the background does not go behind the header.  I can also get the background to go behind the header but then the email link doesn't underline when I hover.  I can't get both to work at the same time.  My website link is http://www.michaelgray.com/hometest.html.  Can someone help me solve this problem?  Thanks.

My contact info code is;

```
.contactinformation {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    z-index: -100;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 135%;
    color: darkblue;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px black;
}
```

My header code is;

```
.header {
    background-color: #00aeef;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px black;

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have your `.contactinformation` `z-index` set to `-100` which causes is it to fall behind the main content. What you need to do is set it to something higher than the body content, but lower than the header.

For `.header` add `position:relative;` (which is necessary for `z-index` to have an effect) and for `.contactinformation` change the `z-index` to `1`. You could also just remove `z-index` from `.contactinformation` completely.

Comment: Questions with external links to the main code shouldn't be answered as when that link die, both your answer and the question will be completely useless to future users

Comment: Nope, you reference _main content_ which is not available, and OP talks about a _email hover_ which is not available.

Comment: @LGSon the code necessary to troubleshoot the issue is present in the question. If you're not happy with my answer, simply move along.

Comment: wow. I'm glad I came here to get my question answered.  That fixed the issue.  I've been struggling with this for several hours.

Comment: @htr5 What `.row`?? ... There is no such info in the question, which proves my point ... This is at best a _guess_, which might or might not solve the issue, and I think we shouldn't be doing that here at SO.

Comment: I'm a newbie here.  The answer I received was excellent and that fixed the problem.  I have a follow-up question I would like to ask.  Can I ask it here on this thread or should I begin a new thread?

Comment: @Mike First, I recommend you edit this question to a proper one, and you can check this link how-to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... Second, sometimes a follow up is close related to the first, then using a comment could be enough, if it is not, a new will be more appropriate. and if you don't know which it is, posting it as a comment could be the first step

Comment: I will attempt to edit the question and certainly remove the .row.  My follow-up is pretty much the same question but for a different webpage.  The webpage is www.michaelgray.com/about.html. Again, my :hover is not working since the main content is overlapping with the header.  The main content it seems is preventing the :hover within the div to work.   I want my main content to be higher (within the z-index) than the header.  I also want my header to be higher than the contact information div.  But since the main content is higher than the contact information div, the hover is not working.

Comment: I figured out what to do.  I fixed the problem.  Thanks anyway.